# Streaming MP4s with PHP

Tags: php, ftp, streaming, mp4

I'm trying to stream mp4 files through FTP and PHP but only mp3s will stream, the mp4s will download but not stream is there a special format that mp4s MUST be in to stream?

This is the code I'm trying:

```
$response =  ftp_raw($ftp, 'SIZE '.$_GET['path']); 
$size = floatval(str_replace('213 ', '', $response[0]));
if(substr($_GET['path'], -4) == '.mp3') {
  header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg, audio/x-mpeg, audio/x-mpeg-3, audio/mpeg3');
}
if(substr($_GET['path'], -4) == ".mp4") {
  header('Content-Type: video/mpeg');
}
header('Content-Encoding: chunked');
header('Connection: keep-alive');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'. basename($_GET["path"]). '"');
header('Content-Description: File Transfer'); 
header("Content-Length: $size");
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary'); 
header('X-Pad: avoid browser bug');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: -1');
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false);
header('Content-Range: bytes 0-'.$size); 
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
$out = fopen('php://output', 'w');
if (!ftp_fget($ftp, $out, $_GET['path'], FTP_BINARY)) die('Unable to get file: ' . $remote_file);
fclose($out);
```

Comment: I've tried content-type: video/mp4 too.

Comment: My guess is that it has something to do with the `Content-Range` header.  The client may be asking for a certain chunk of the file, but you are sending the entire file.  Also, I don't know if `Content-Encoding: chunked` is needed here or not.

Comment: Are your MP4 files encoded to allow streaming?

Comment: @datasage: Is there a type of encoding that *doesn't* allow streaming?

Comment: @RocketHazmat Yes. It has to do with something called the Moov-Atom. If this is at the end of the file, it will not steam. Certain encoders will put it at the end of the file. [Technical info from Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/video/articles/mp4_movie_atom.html).

Comment: @datasage that is what I was wondering, how would you enable streaming, do you have a quick an easy method?  I was thinking that was the case.

Comment: There are tools that can switch the Moov-atom to the start of the file. I don't know one off the top of my head, but you should be able to find something on google for your environment. Its probably best do this on the original files as stored on your ftp server.

Comment: found this...http://renaun.com/blog/code/qtindexswapper/

I'll try it when I get home, thanks for telling me what the issue was!

Answer (score 1):

You need a stream server of some sort. If you really want to do that with PHP, which I stongly discourage, then you will need to open a socket connection and write chunks of data that you will be sequentially reading from the file ... in a loop until you go through the entire file.

Considering the fact that you should be also considering concurrency and proper memory management, and considering how php is (overhead, not thread friendly ... or so I have been told, ...), just don't do that with PHP.

There are plenty of open source streaming solutions around and their will meet your need.

Yep, PHP is not really meant for that ... though it is possible in theory.

Anyone please correct me if I wrong.